# Website not displayed properly in Safari

Tags: html, safari, cross-browser

My website [www.dshinestudio.com](http://www.dshinestudio.com) is not displaying properly in Safari, but it is displayed correctly in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and other browsers.

Why isn't Safari displaying my website properly? 
Do I need to add anything in my code?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Some Safari extensions that block ads or other website content can prevent some page elements from displaying. You can temporarily turn off extensions, then re-load the page to see if this is the issue.

```
Choose Safari > Preferences.
Click Extensions.
Select an extension, then deselect the checkbox "Enable… extension." Repeat this step for every extension that's currently installed.
```

Reload the page by choosing Choose View > Reload in Safari. If the webpage loads correctly, one or more extensions was blocking the content from loading. Re-enable an extensi

Comment: There is no extensions in my safari browser. What to do ?